# has any way let php to detect front-end routing changes?(angular)

Tags: php, angular

I have an angular form embedded in a php page. When the angular form is sent out, it will navigate to some page.

In practice, when angular form after completing, will use：
router.navigate or router.navigateByUrl to a specific route. And those routes have exactly the same page in php.

Example:

in angular

```
...
this.router.navigate([done], { queryParams: { anyKey: 'anyValue' }});
...
```

in php

```
...
done.php

<?php
echo('I got it');
?>
```

But in reality we know that done.php will never say "I got it" because done.php has never been executed at all.

The problem is that php does not detect the front-end routing was change happen. I understand that this makes sense, but has any way to let php know that the front-end routing has changed?

thank any help.

Answer (score 1):

when you are using a frontend framework like react, angular, vue and so on the frontend and backend should only communicate with each others through APIs so if you want php to collect the form data that you just submitted then you should send these data to php through an API and after receiving the response from php then you can route the user to the done route

but without APIs the php will never know what’s happening on the user side because it's all handled through JS

Comment: Yes, I totally understand this, the backend role should play purely api.The problem now is that after the front end finishes the form (including all the communication with the api), I eventually need to run the gtag conversion rate, something I've already done in angular. Unfortunately, my boss didn't trust the gtag conversion rate tracking run by the front-end (he get mad to see the low numbers, not considering that maybe the consumer didn't want to spend for a while?) So I had to do it in php (he said: never a problem in php),hence this story.

Comment: but don't worry, I seem to have come up with an ancient solution and am testing it at ....

Comment: The interesting thing is that I explained to him that a low number and a zero number are two different things, a low number means that it is still working and only when the number is zero am I willing to consider whether angular is wrong, but he is the boss.

Comment: @PorkJackson ok why not call an API to handle this on `ngOnInit` for example or any other component life cycle event based on your use case I believe it will be the same thing

Comment: because redirecting the user to another page will require reinitialize the entire angular

Comment: Do you mean the gtag is sent via the api command backend? About gtag I never thought of this method, ok I can try it, thank you for your advice.

Comment: gtag is sending an API to google under the hood but what I meant is aside from gtag you can call an API that do exactly what the `done.php` would have done and call this API in `ngOnInit` in the component that you redirect the user to after submission

Answer (score 0):

Yes, eventually I came up with a very old solution.

```
window.location.href= 'some where' ;
```

This solved my problem because my boss wanted the gtag conversion rate tracking code to 'must' run in php and he didn't trust angular to run it, so I had to find a way around it.

I would welcome any answers, even though it has been solved using ancient methods.